# Tableau GAP & forecasting formula & displaying monthwise+quarterly

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I've excel datasource (as greyed below) and I want to show 4 calculated fields (CF) as (red highlighted) for 4 "Team" as highlighted in yellow. Output required is green highlighted.

[image]

Output I got as shown in image:

[image]

**Problems faced:**

1. Not able to find right answer for Forecast and GAP. Formuales
   used are below:
2. How to represent ONLY (# of Sales) monthwise but display all 4 CFs at QUARTER levels as shown in the green above.

   ```
   # of sales = COUNT([Productname])

   Days Passed = DAY([Sale Date])-day(TODAY())

   Forecast = (([#ofSales]))/(avg([DaysPassed]))*avg([TotalDays])

   SalesTarget (copy) = { FIXED [Team], quarter([Sale Date])=1 : avg([SalesTarget])}

   GAP = (sum([SalesTarget (copy)]))-[Forecast]

   TotalDays = if quarter([Sale Date])=1 then 91 
       ELSEIF quarter([Sale Date])=2 then 92
       ELSEIF quarter([Sale Date])=3 then 92
       ELSEIF quarter([Sale Date])=4 then 92 end

   SalesTarget = if [Team]="USA Small" and quarter([Sale Date])=1 then 10
       ELSEIF [Team]="USA Big" and quarter([Sale Date])=1 then 5
       ELSEIF [Team]="UK Small" and quarter([Sale Date])=1 then 3
       ELSEIF [Team]="UK Big" and quarter([Sale Date])=1 then 3
       END

   SalesTarget (copy) = { FIXED [Team], quarter([Sale Date])=1 : avg([SalesTarget])}
   ```

I've tried multiple workarounds but couldn't find solution. I can't attach any file in Stack Overflow. So added just few code samples, I'd tried out of many.